# how to define two pipes in the same component

Tags: html, angular

I want to know how to define two pipes in the same component.
Here, i want to define two transforms in my component.
One is already defined -

**transaction.component.ts**

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({  
   name: 'orderBy','filterpipe'

 })

export class TransactionComponent implements OnInit ,PipeTransform{

public transform(array: any[], reverse: boolean = false, prop?: 
string) {

//code

}

transform(customers: Customer[], args: any[]): any {
return customers.filter(customer => 
customer.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1);
 }

//code
}
```

But here i am unable to define two names in one pipe.

I get error -

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; 'filterpipe': any; }' is not 
assignable to parameter of type 'Pipe'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''filterpipe'' 
does not exist in type 'Pipe'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is forcing developers to write one class per file which is a good practice. If you want to create few different `Pipe`s you can do it by creating few different files. For example:

```
@Pipe({  
  name: 'orderBy'
})

export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform{

  public transform(array: any[], reverse: boolean = false, prop?: 
  string) {

   //code

}
```

Other Pipe:

```
@Pipe({  
  name: 'filterpipe'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform{

  public transform(array: any[], reverse: boolean = false, prop?: 
  string) {

   //code

}
```

You have to add your `Pipe`s to module declaration too if you want to use them in your components.
Also be careful about naming your Pipe classes, I can see that you named it `TransactionComponent` and it really doesn't have anything to do with any component. Pipe classes should be generic and do only one thing [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define two pipe in same file. you should define two pipe using different files.

```
@Pipe({  
   name: 'orderBy'
 })
```

and

```
@Pipe({  
   name: 'filterpipe'
 })
```

In HTML, its a sample

```
 <div *ngFor="let l of listings | orderBy:'TEST' | filterpipe:'ACTIVE'  ">
```

Comment: but i want them in the same html page

Comment: you can use in the same html using |

Comment: OP is asking for two pipes in HTML file, isn't it?

Comment: yeah two pipes in html file

Comment: That's wrong for angular 9+. In fact, you can have more than one pipe definition in the same `.pipe.ts` file as any other decorator. Isn't a good practise, but you can...

Answer (score 0):

companyone.pipe.ts

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Company} from './company';


@Pipe({
    name: 'companyone'
})

export class CompanyOnePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(obj: Company): string {

    let output = obj.cname+' : '+ obj.location;

    return output;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 7 (I think newest versions also) you can have several pipes in the same file, adding a new decorator for each one as below.

I'm not sure if is the best practice, but you can do something like:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform, *} from "@angular"

@Pipe({
   name: "myPipe1"
})
export class myPipe1 implements PipeTransform {
    return null;
}

@Pipe({
   name: "myPipe2"
})
export class myPipe2 implements PipeTransform {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Angular 7 is a heavily outdated version which is out of support. The latest version is v16. https://angular.io/guide/releases#actively-supported-versions